# Html DOM to Array Buffer to make BLOB for pdf?

Tags: javascript, typescript, blob, arraybuffer

I want to show my HTML DOM as pdf in new tab using BLOB. We can achieve this by calling a API which will return a blob but I want to do this without the involvement of any server side API. I am facing problems in converting my html string to ARRAY BUFFER. Here is the code on stackblitz you can test this and please let me know how to solve this. Thanks

[generate pdf from html dom](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-clrg5r)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [TextEncoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder), which can easily encode/decode Strings and ArrayBuffers:

```
const encoder = new TextEncoder(),
      decoder = new TextDecoder(),
      text = 'Hello',
      textEncoded = encoder.encode(text),
      textDecoded = decoder.decode(textEncoded);

console.log({ text, textDecoded, textEncoded });
```